# EIP Router usage without introducing a new channel after

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

Is it possible don't to create a new channel after Router usage in Spring Integration in such scenario:

1. using a Router of some type (e.g. `HeaderValueRouter`)
2. on a basis 1 do some different things (e.g. if a message header has a parameter with value A will do actionA, if the parameter has value B will do actionB etc.)
3. do next common things

Here steps 1-2 isn't actually define different paths of execution but only temp branching.

Currently I have to extract 3 and others integration steps into a separate flow definition with a new direct input channel and use this channel name at step 2. The solution looks artificial and cumbersome.

May I don't do this somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all let's take a look at like it is an [EIP component](http://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/patterns/messaging/MessageRouter.html):

> a Message Router, which consumes a Message from one Message Channel and republishes it to a different Message Channel channel depending on a set of conditions.

From other side to reach the best *loosely coupling* and better modularity, the router knows nothing about donwstream flow - just only its input channel to router.

If you would like to have some simple `if...else` logic, but don't involve the messaging in the logic, you could just compose that logic in some POJO method and with the `.handle()` you will be able to reach the desired behavior.

The router must only route, nothing more!

From other side to make the DSL a bit useful we have introduced the `subflow` notation and you can map routing logic using [`subFlowMapping`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-java-dsl/wiki/Spring-Integration-Java-DSL-Reference#subflows):

```
    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow routerTwoSubFlows() {
        return f -> f
                .split()
                .<Integer, Boolean>route(p -> p % 2 == 0, m -> m
                        .subFlowMapping("true", sf -> sf.<Integer>handle((p, h) -> p * 2))
                        .subFlowMapping("false", sf -> sf.<Integer>handle((p, h) -> p * 3)))
                .aggregate()
                .channel(c -> c.queue("routerTwoSubFlowsOutput"));
    }
```

> The `.channelMapping()` continues to work as in regular Router mapping, but the `.subFlowMapping()` tied that subflow with main flow. In other words, any router's subflow returns to the main flow after `.route()`.

Comment: Thanks again for your helpful answer!

I'm absolutely agree with `EIP Router` classic behavior and `subFlowMapping` extension is exactly I'm looking for. This will definitely simplify my flow(s)!

Is it possible to specify somehow `switch...case...default` behavior? I need to specify `default` execution branch if no others alternatives were chosen by router.

Comment: ` switch...case...default ` can be as a part of `.route()` Lambda, and you in the end add one more `subFlowMapping("default"`)`.

Comment: I understood you point and in some cases it's possible to implement as you suggested but... not always and it would be better to have dedicated DSL instruction for `default` execution branch or channel.

Comment: Let's move this discussion to your appropriate GH issue: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-java-dsl/issues/77 !